# find users whose non-uid attributes are identical

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the table

```
CREATE TABLE Permission (uid char(32), pid char(32), term char(32),
PRIMARY KEY (uid, pid, term))
```

Containing values such as

```
uid    pid    term
0001   1001   3                            
0001   1002   3                            
0001   1002   4                            
0002   1001   3                            
0002   1002   3                            
0002   1002   4                            
0003   1001   3                            
0003   1002   4                            
0003   1002   5
```

I want to return the uid of all users who have identical pid and term values, in this example I'd want 0001 and 0002, but I can't figure out how to compare each uid's pid and term values to the each of the other uid's pid and term values.  The closest I have been able to get is determining if each user has duplicate pids.

```
SELECT uid
FROM Permission
GROUP BY uid, pid
HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

Which I'm not even sure is related to the test I want to perform. and

```
SELECT uid
FROM (SELECT P1.uid, P1.pid
      FROM Permission P1
      WHERE EXISTS (SELECT P2.pid
                    FROM Permission P2
                    WHERE P1.pid = P2.pid)) P
GROUP BY P.uid
HAVING COUNT (P.pid) = (SELECT COUNT (P3.pid)
                        FROM Permission P3
                        WHERE P3.uid = P.uid)
```

Which I think should work, but I'm obviously wrong as it just returns all uids =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join and aggregation:

```
with p as (
      select p.*, count(*) over (partition by uid) as cnt
      from permissions p
     )
select p1.uid, p2.uid
from p p1 join
     p p2
     on p1.pid = p2.pid and
        p1.term = p2.term and
        p1.cnt = p2.cnt and
        p1.uid < p2.uid
group by p1.uid, p2.uid, p1.cnt
having count(*) = p1.cnt;
```

Comment: It isn't mandatory, this solution does what it needs to, but in cases where there are more than 2 with the same this returns for example if 1, 2 and 4 all match (1, 2) (1, 4) (2,4).  What would be a fast way to combine all of those into ones solution (1, 2, 4), whether tuple, string, or other?

Comment: You might want to ask that as another question.  The answer might look quite different.

Comment: Okay, It was more of a curiosity than a requirement, if I need to pursue it I will take your advice, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

group by all three of your columns

```
SELECT uid, pid, term
FROM PERMISSION
GROUP BY uid, pid, term
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

and you can select from that if you needed only a single column

```
SELECT DISTINCT uid 
FROM (
  SELECT uid, pid, term
  FROM PERMISSION
  GROUP BY uid, pid, term
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t
```